# How does tslearn TimeSeriesKMeans calulates its metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I now this mind sound stupid but I haven't found and exact answer to this. I am trying to use the [tslearn library](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to cluster time series in some K groups. My question is in regards to how extactly the library extracts features from the time series so they can be used as a input for the Kmeans algorithm.

For example in the sample code bellow,

```
import numpy as np
from tslearn.clustering import TimeSeriesKMeans

X = np.random.random((10,100))
km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=3, metric="euclidean").fit_predict(X)
```

How is the euclidian distance used?
Is the distance calculated for every pair of of Time Series (making a 10x10 matrix of distances)?

My problem is that this sounds too much ineficitient to be true. Specialy when you change the euclidian distance for other metrics. DTW, for example, is way more complex to calculate and generating the full matrix would be extremely slow.